# Seeing "Error: Rake tasks fetching failed with..." Under NetBeans?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans

Netbeans seems to be throwing this error:

```
"Error: Rake tasks fetching failed with..."
```

whenever I start it up, though otherwise it's fine. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is due to the default setting in NetBeans which selects JRuby as the Ruby Platform, when (in my case) Ruby 1.8.6-p287 (or whatever your Ruby install is) should have been. To fix this, right click on the directory > properties - select an alternate Ruby Platform.

[Screen Shot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/004a78e48e.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/004a78e48e.png)

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRubyRakeFetchingFailed